# Filter unique array values and sum values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filtering

I have the following js array:

```
for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
  arr.push([array[j][0],array[j][1],array[j][2]]);
}
```

And it translates into this:

**Number, type, qty**

```
[[12345, "product", "10"],[12345, "product", "15"],[1234567, "other", "10"]]
```

What I've been trying to do is to filter the unique product number **array[j][0]** and sum the qty **array[j][2]** if there's more than one  and I was able to do the unique filter by doing the following:

```
for(var o = 0; o < arr.length; o++){
  if (!n[arr[o][1]]){
     n[arr[o][1]] = true
     r.push(arr[o]);
  }
}
```

I would like your help to figure this out.. What I'm expecting to achieve is something like this:

```
[[12345, "product", "25"],[1234567, "other", "10"]]
```

Since product 12345 was repeated I only need to display it once and sum the qty of the other products with the same product number.

Comment: So you want a hash of product IDs and their running totals?

Comment: Yes, filtering out the unique numbers and adding up the totals @DaveNewton

Comment: (That was hint: use the hash to track IDs, when you iterate over an item with an existing array, do math; when you find an ID w/o a value, create the new entry with the price.)

Comment: Have you considered moving this piece of business logic to the back end? In a production system, it's going to be much easier and more efficient to write queries to achieve what you want.

Comment: @NicholasByfleet My guess is that this is an assignment, so it would not matter.

Comment: This is actually a javascript in google spreadsheet so you I guess you can say is in the backend.. @NicholasByfleet

Dave I'll give that a try i just didn't want to iterate and loop into each one of the values in the array.. wanted to see if there was a simpler way to do it within this part of my code (code block 3)

Comment: @CCastillo I understand now. You should use a pivot table then.

Comment: Yeah that would be a solution, though I'm getting values from multiple spreadsheets and transposing data through a google script and wanted to do everything through the script @NicholasByfleet

Comment: @CCastillo Have you tried using VMerge from the Script gallery to get all of the values and then pivot? Sorry if I'm asking you questions that you've already thought of... just trying to help you avoid JS for a spreadsheet that (potentially) less technical colleagues may need to edit in the future.

Comment: try with **[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**. See my answer below.

Comment: should the sum be a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var productIndex = {};
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var productId = arr[i][0];
  if (productIndex[productId] === undefined) {
    productIndex[productId] = result.length;
    result.push(arr[i]);
  } else {
    var index = productIndex[productId];
    result[index][2] = String(+result[index][2] + +arr[i][2]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see where you are going with this, it makes sense. I haven't been able to make it work though

Comment: What are you having trouble with? It works for your sample array.

Comment: My mistake was replacing === with ==

This works!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are better ways. But I just changed it to an object, added them and changed it back to an array. Here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/ct6to1Lv/

```
var a = [[12345, "product", "10"],[12345, "product", "15"],[1234567, "other", "10"]];
var b = {};
var c = [];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(!b.hasOwnProperty(a[i][0])) {
    b[a[i][0]] = {};
    b[a[i][0]]['qty'] = 0;
  }
  b[a[i][0]]['id'] = a[i][0];
  b[a[i][0]]['name'] = a[i][1];
    b[a[i][0]]['qty'] += parseInt(a[i][2]);
}

for(key in b) {
    c[c.length] = [b[key]['id'], b[key]['name'], b[key]['qty']];
}

$(function(){
$('#console').append(a.toString()+'<br />');
$('#console').append(JSON.stringify(b)+'<br />');
$('#console').append(c.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [[12345, "product", "10"],[12345, "product", "15"],[1234567, "other", "10"]];

var obj = {};

arr.forEach(function(e){
    var t = e[0];
    if(obj[t]) {
        obj[t][2] += +e[2];
    } else {
        t = [];
        t[0] = e[0];
        t[1] = e[1];
        t[2] = +e[2];
        obj[e[0]] = t;
    }
});

var res = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    res.push(obj[k]);
});

console.log(res);
```

Result:

```
[ [ 12345, 'product', 25 ], [ 1234567, 'other', 10 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`reduce()`** method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

See **[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** and **[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**

```
var list = [[12345, "product", "10"], [12345, "product", "15"], [1234567, "other", "10"], [12345, "product", "5"]];

//first we sort the array by id
//@pv = previous value; @cv = current value
list.sort(function(pv, cv) {
    var a = +pv[0],
        b = +cv[0];
    return a - b;
});

//reduce the array for repeated elements
//@pv = previous value; @cv = current value
var reduced = list.reduce(function (pv, cv) {
    //slice keeps reference when element is an object/array
    var last = pv.slice(-1)[0];
    if (last === undefined) return [cv];
    //compares the id
    if (last[0] == cv[0]) 
        last[2] = +last[2] + (+cv[2]); //sums values
    else pv.push(cv); //order elements
    return pv;
}, []); //[] initial value for @pv

console.log(reduced);
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the possibillities, here a solution with a temporary object, which is hidden in `this`.

```js
var data = [[12345, "product", "10"], [12345, "product", "15"], [1234567, "other", "10"]],
    result = function (data) {
        var r = [];
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!this[a[0]]) {
                this[a[0]] = [a[0], a[1], 0];
                r.push(this[a[0]]);
            }
            this[a[0]][2] += +a[2];
        }, {});
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```